# VMWare Player 15.5 controls not showing?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-workstation-player

[image]

There are usually some controls here in Workstation i.e. view, menu

For some reason I cannot see them and there seems to be no option to enable the controls?

Answer (score 0):

Player is not Workstation (I Have Workstation here). You can pull down Player but otherwise, I think that is all you get.

Workstation is the vastly better product.